# Distribution of the $\alpha$-parameter of a $2\times 2$ Haar-distributed, unitary matrix

Tags: probability-distributions, random-matrices, matrix-theory

It is well known that any $2\times 2$ unitary matrix $\mathbf{U}$ can be parametrized as
$$\mathbf{U}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{j}\beta_1}\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \cos\alpha & -\sin\alpha \\ \sin\alpha & \cos\alpha\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{j}\beta_2}\ & 0 \\ 0 & \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{j}\beta_3}\end{pmatrix}.$$

The question is, if $\mathbf{U}$ is Haar-distributed, what is the distribution of $\alpha$?

Answer (score 1):

The distribution you are seeking is:
$$P(\alpha)=\sin(2\alpha),\;\;\alpha\in[0,\pi/2]$$

The general way to derive the Haar measure for any parameterization of $U$ in terms of variables $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots$, is to calculate the metric tensor
$$g_{mn}=-{\rm Tr}\,U^\dagger(\partial U/\alpha_m)U^\dagger(\partial U/\partial\alpha_n)$$
Then the distribution $P(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots)$ follows from $P\propto\sqrt{{\rm Det}\,g}$.

Comment: Carlo, thanks for your answer. It fits well our observations. Would you mind recommending some good references where I can learn more on this topic?

Comment: well, there is not much more than I write here; if you are interested in the Haar measure for a variety of parameterizations of different compact groups, you might take a look at Appendix B.1 of http://arxiv.org/abs/1405.3115